# Not able to use my custom google app without pushtotalk file

Tags: raspberry-pi3, google-assistant-sdk, home-automation

I have a working google assistant app. Also Google has released it. How to use it on my device without using pushtotalk file?

Answer (score 0):

Good morning, Rajas. [This Raspberry Pi Google assistant project](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-google-assistant/) will walk you through on how to build and set up your very own Pi-powered Google Assistant.